# openFrameworks Visual Studio Setup Tutorial?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, openframeworks

I've been trying to get oF examples to compile with Visual Studio, but I'm either missing a link or something.. Is there a tutorial on how to setup oF with Visual Studio 2010 (or 2008 - or any version)? If not, can someone provide step-by-step directions on setting up oF with Visual Studio?

(Unfortunately, the oF website doesn't provide any info on setting up oF with VS. Their VS link just tells you how to download VS o.O http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/vs-2008 )

Comment: Seriously. It's the weird they tell you how to install VS :x

Answer (score 3):

There is a short Tutorial how to setup Openframeworks and Visual Studio 2010
in the OpenFrameworks Forum.

[link to article](http://www.openframeworks.cc/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3899&sid=601a3b946e5d73794a4dc42dd5170dac)

I haven't tried it yet, but it seems ok to me. Zach event hosts prebuild libraries for Visual Studio 2010 (poco comes to mind). They are currently working on a 2010 Version by the way.

Edit December 2010: The people at openframeworks released a new version 0.062 which is available for Visual Studio 2010. You can find it here: [link text](http://www.openframeworks.cc/versions/preRelease_v0.062/of_preRelease_v0062_vs2010_FAT.zip)